# What does $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Find $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s}(f\circ T)(1, 0)$, where $f(u, v) = \cos u \sin v$
and $T:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is defined by
$T(s, t) = (\cos (t^2s), \log\sqrt{1+s^2})$

I apologize if this is a very basic concept, but what does the $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ mean?

Comment: It means $T$ is a function with domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Simply put, it means $T$ maps an ordered pair of real numbers to an ordered pair of real numbers.  Thus, $T$ maps a point in the $st$-plane to a point in the $uv$-plane and $s,t,u,v$ are all real numbers.

Comment: So is it similar to the idea of one input leads to only one output?

Comment: Yes, the notation $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is used exclusively in the context of single-valued functions.

Answer (score 1):

It means from pairs of reals to pairs of reals.

Answer (score 1):

$T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ means that $T$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, $T$ associates a point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a **unique** point of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This is surprizing that you never encountered this notation before but you still now partial derivatives. There is no shame though.

Comment: What if it was R -> R^2 or R^2 -> R? I actually never bothered to learn the notation since it never seemed to affect how I solve the problems which I realize is probably screwing me over in the long run.

Comment: Another notation you might see is $\mathbb{R} \times  \mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Either way, it means an ordered pair of reals.  Example of $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is mapping a latitude and longitude to the distance from a landmark.  Example of $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is mapping the time (of day) to the latitude and longitude of the sun.

Answer (score 1):

It means your function $T$ takes an element from $\mathbb R^2$ and maps it to an element in $\mathbb R^2$. The first set is called the domain and the second set is called the codomain.